# How to Map a Test Project to a Project in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, nunit

I'm having a C# Class Library project and I created a Unit Test Project in the same solution (Manually created). I need to map this manually created project into the actual Library project.

I wrote a method in the Library project and I right clicked the method and I selected the "**Create Unit Test**", it shows the following dialog

[image]

There is no option to select the existing Test Project. Structure of the solution is

[image]

Kindly assist me how to map the manually created Test Project in this dialog.

Comment: What template did you use for the test project? or show a screenshot of all projects in the solution

Comment: Add a Reference to the library project in the test project. No difference from how you do it with any other project references.

Comment: @zaitsman I added a structure of the solution.

Comment: @Crowcoder Yes I added a reference too...

Comment: You can just write your tests in the test project. If you need to generate them from the library project then I would say delete your test project and let the dialog create a new one.